# Mongodb dot notation wildcard?

Tags: mongodb, syntax

I have a collection of users, each of which may be subscribed to one or more services. Each service has some meta data, including the number of credits the user has for that service.

How can I find all of the user objects who have less than 50 credits for some service if I have no way of knowing what the service objects keys will be?

Conceptually, it would be something like this, which doesn't work:

```
db.users.find({services.*.credits : {$lt : 50}})
```

The users collection:

```
   {
_id: 4f0ea25072139e4d2000001f,
services : {
    a : { credits : 100, score : 2000 },
    b : { credits : 200, score : 300 },
    c : { credits : 10, score : 1300 }
    }
},
{
_id: 4f0ea25072139e4d2000001f,
services : {
    f : { credits : 68, score : 14 },
    q : { credits : 1000, score : 102 },
    z : { credits : 59, score : 352 }
    }
}
```

Another example of what I want to do, in case it's not clear here, is explained here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#comment-346075854

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I think it would be easier if you put that services object into an array, so you can use `$elemMatch`, like:

```
{
  services : [
    {key: "a" , credits : 100, score : 2000 },
    {key: "b", credits : 200, score : 300 },
    {key: "c", credits : 10, score : 1300 }
  ]
}
```

and

```
{
  _id: 4f0ea25072139e4d2000001f,
  services : [
    {key: "f", credits : 68, score : 14 },
    {key: "q", credits : 1000, score : 102 },
    {key: "z", credits : 59, score : 352 }
  ]
}
```

Then the query you would write would be like this:

```
db.coll.find({services: {$elemMatch : {credits: {$lt: 50}}}});
```

result:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f0f2be07561bf94ea47eec4"), "services" : [  {   "key" : "a", "credits" : 100, "score" : 2000 }, { "key" : "b", "credits" : 200, "score" : 300 },    {   "key" : "c",    "credits" : 10,     "score" : 1300 } ] }
```

Comment: I did end up changing our schema to just use an array. I could have used $elemMatch, but since I only needed to match on a single criteria, I was able to do: `db.users.find({services.credits : {$lt:50}})`

Comment: -1 because this is not an answer to the question. Not everyone has the ability to change the schema of the data they are working with. This question remains unanswered.

Comment: OK I answered it myself. Found a way to do it. Posted below.

Answer (score 28):

This is an actual answer to your question.

How you can find all of the user objects who have less than 50 credits for some service if you have no way of knowing what the service objects keys will be is as follows.

Use a $where query:

```
db.users.find({
    $where: function () {
        for (var index in this.services)
            if (this.services[index].credits < 50)
                return this;
    }
});
```

Comment: Your 'query' lacks index support entirely. There's just no reason to use a data structure like this; if you can't even simulate an index, you're performing a collection scan every time and you could just as well load the entire collection in RAM and scan it there, which then is a trivial exercise in JavaScript.

Comment: He asked, "How can I find all of the user objects who have less than 50 credits for some service if I have no way of knowing what the service objects keys will be?" I answered his question. I didn't downvote the "answerers" just the answers, because they weren't answers. They were people saying, "You can't/shouldn't do that" when clearly you can, and it's a purely a matter of opinion as to whether you should. I disagree that "there's just no reason to use data structure like this" ... there are plenty of great reasons to do so. Just because you don't know them, isn't really my fault nor op's.

Comment: I don't look at people's rep I just read the answer. I don't doubt that you know more about MongoDB than I do. But if it's not an answer to the question that was asked then I am obliged to downvote it; I'm not going to not do so simply because you have a high rep. Telling someone there is no way to do something, when in fact there is, is not cool. Telling people that their data structure is pointless just because you don't see the point of it, is not cool either. Maybe they have a great reason for using it which you simply don't understand. Maybe if you asked what the point is you might learn.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with what @CommaToast is saying here. I have needed to run a one-off query to determine if certain data is missing in the database to decide if code changes need to be made. The database already exists and there is no issue with the data structure in any way. There was no way I was going to update the preexisting data structure to track down a couple of minor issues. To suggest doing so in favour of providing an actual solution is plain ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to accomplish this using the schema you're using. It seems to me you're abusing objects as arrays. If `services` were an array (the plural hints that it should be), you could simply query

```
db.users.find({"services.credits" : { $lt : 50 }});
```

or use `$elemMatch` if you need to match multiple conditions on a single array element.

Comment: What I really wanted was associative arrays, which would prevent me from having two array elements for the same service id. Our users should never end up with `{services:[{service:f,credits 50},{service:f,credits:60}]}`. An associative array enforces this, and makes 90% of our lookups trivial. 

Using regular arrays forces me to search the array first before doing queries to see if I need to add to the services array or find an element and update it.

Comment: Almost all consistency checking must be done in code. That is also true for associative arrays. MongoDB does not support constraints in embedded documents: http://waistcode.net/blog/unique-array-keys-in-mongodb, i.e. an object can't 'violate itself'.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. @stuporglue's comment above explains a perfectly valid and great reason to have created his data model the way he did. It's the same reason our data model was done the way we did it. And I still need an answer to this question. People saying they don't know the answer, or accusing people of abusing things, etc., is just unproductive.