# MongoDB Query inner collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with the following structure,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("551f479ffd23fd19d73cca8b"),
    "305" : {
        "concept" : "C288",
        "id" : 305,
        "code" : "C304",
        "Display_Name" : "Clearance",
        "NUI" : "N0000000063",
        "RxNorm_CUI" : "986535",
        "UMLS_CUI" : "C2825073",
        "kindname" : "PHARMACOKINETICS_KIND",
        "name" : "Clearance [PK]"
    }
}
```

I want to retrieve the document by matching RxNorm_CUI value in my find operation. Could anyone please help me with the query.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  When asking a question here, it's usually a good idea to also post what you've tried so far and what issues you faced.  For your question, a simple find query like `db.collection.find({"305.RxNorm_CUI":"986535"})` should help.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/): `MongoDB uses the dot notation to access the elements of an array and to access the fields of an embedded document.`

Comment: Thank you that, This is kind of my first post here on SO.

Comment: I was using db.ndf.find({'RxNorm_CUI':'991181'}, {'_id':0}) when my document structure was as below,
{
    "code" : "C178",
    "Display_Name" : "Chemical Ingredients",
    "name" : "Chemical Ingredients [Chemical/Ingredient]",
    "UMLS_CUI" : "C0085993",
    "NUI" : "N0000000002",
    "RxNorm_CUI" : "991181",
    "kindname" : "INGREDIENT_KIND",
    "id" : 179
}
but that does not help when its of structure as mentioned above.
The problem is I have access to only RxNorm_CUI value and have to retrieve based on that. Wont know 305. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: That's not possible.  Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179871/mongodb-wildcard-in-the-key-of-a-query) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840342/mongodb-dot-notation-wildcard) and

Comment: Thank you for that. Will change my design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first create a query object that has the concept id as a key. For instance:

```
var query = {},
    concept_id = 305; // this can be a dynamic value
query[concept_id].RxNorm_CUI = "986535";
```

This will create query object:

```
query = {
    "305": {
        "RxNorm_CUI": "986535"
    }
};
```

which you can then use as the [**`findOne()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne) query:

`db.collection.findOne(query`);

Comment: Thanks for this is there any way to do it with out using concept_id and only the RxNorm_CUI as this is the only value I have access to compare.

Comment: @shreekanthk.s The problem with a design where you have dynamic keys like `"305"` is they are difficult to query where you don't know the keys beforehand, it's considered bad design practice. Since you only know the field `RxNorm_CUI` exists, it would be hard to query that since it's a property of a nested document within a dynamic keyed parent. If you knew the key beforehand then your query would use the dot notation `db.collection.findOne({ "305.RxNorm_CUI": "986535" });` The approach that I mentioned in my answer also works.