# filter query in mongodb with nested json

Tags: json, mongodb, filter

I have a mongoDB collection that I need ti filter to get the students where "state" is "CA . The collection looks like this

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("112233"),
"John" : {
    "age" : "20",
    "gender" : "male",
    "result" : "pass",
    "state" : "CA"
},
"Sam" : {
    "age" : "24",
    "gender" : "male",
    "result" : "pass",
    "state" : "NV"
},
"Emily" : {
    "age" : "21",
    "gender" : "Female",
    "result" : "pass",
    "state" : "CA"
},
"Paul" : {
    "age" : "22",
    "gender" : "Male",
    "result" : "pass",
    "state" : "CA"
}
```

}

I tried $filter but could not get that to work as it throws this error "too many recursion"

Comment: you can only use $filter on array, so you can't use it directly on these documents

Comment: Any idea what can be used instead of filter?

Comment: This is not possible with your current document structure, with or without $filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$redact`.

`$redact` to go through a document level at a time and look for `state` field recursively and perform `$$DESCEND` and `$$PRUNE` on the criteria.

The only thing to note is usage of `$ifNull` in the first document level which doesn't have a `$state` field and we assign a value of `CA` so that you can `$$DESCEND` to embedded document level for further processing.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    "$redact": {
        "$cond": [{
                $eq: [{
                    $ifNull: ["$state", "CA"]
                }, "CA"]
            },
            "$$DESCEND",
            "$$PRUNE"
        ]
    }
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is quite possible with the current schema that you have.
What I think you should do is have a collection called students and move the name inside the document with the key name.

so it might look like this:

```
{
    "age" : "22",
    "gender" : "Male",
    "result" : "pass",
    "state" : "CA",
    "name": "Paul"
},
{
    "age" : "21",
    "gender" : "Female",
    "result" : "pass",
    "state" : "CA",
    "name": "Emily"
},
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840342/mongodb-dot-notation-wildcard) may also be useful.